# requests экранирование экранирования?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, requests

Я экранирую бэк слэшем некоторые кавычки, как это требует документация API:

```
import requests
r = requests.post(f"https://iiko.biz:9900/api/0/events/eventsMetadata?access_token={token}&request_timeout={requestTimeout}", json= {"organizationId" : organizainonId, "eventsSettings": "{\"fromRevision\": \"-1\", \"dateFrom\": \"2020-07-07 12:00:00\", \"dateTo\": \"2020-08-11 12:00:00\"}"})
```

Но, когда я выполняю r.request.body , то вижу там следующее:

```
b'{"organizationId": "83xxxx1-xxxx-11e7-xxxx-d8d382565926f", "eventsSettings": "{\\"fromRevision\\": \\"-1\\", \\"dateFrom\\": \\"2020-07-07 12:00:00\\", \\"dateTo\\": \\"2020-08-11 12:00:00\\"}"}'
```

Тоесть был добавлен еще один бэк слэш, там где я экранировал двойные кавычки. Как это пофиксить?

Пример body, который должен улетать на сервер:

```
{
    "organizationId" : "D688C80B-91B3-4829-AC26-43D7CDE8CD3D",
    "eventsSettings" : "{
        \"fromRevision\" : \"-1\",
        \"dateFrom\" : \"2018-12-01 12:00:00\",
        \"dateTo\" : \"2018-12-02 12:00:00\"
    }"
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, если завернуть строку в одинарные кавычки, то слэши не нужны `'{"fromRevision": "-1", ...'` и получится абсолютно то же самое

Comment: Это представление строки. Вы ведь видите не саму строку, а внутри другой строки `b'...'` На самом деле там нормально с слешами. Кроме того, если бы вы использовали апострофы `'`, то не пришлось бы экранировать кавычки

Comment: Во-вторых, вполне логично, что при выводе bytes-объекта на экран Python будет экранировать спецсимволы, чтобы на выходе получился корректный bytes-литерал. Реально в r.request.body хранится ровно один слэш и на сервер улетает тоже один слэш

Comment: Зачем вы формируете json вручную? Создайте python-словарь с нужными значениями и скормите `json.dumps()`. Так вы точно избежите подобных проблем

Comment: Как написали в комментариях, в запросе все ок, на сервер улетает то что нужно, а я видел лишь определенное представление строки. Со слэшами было все нормально по факту.

Answer (score 1):

Для корректного формирования json-файлов нужно пользоваться функцией `dumps` модуля `json`

```py
import json
import requests

js_data = {
    "organizationId" : "D688C80B-91B3-4829-AC26-43D7CDE8CD3D",
    "eventsSettings" : {
        "fromRevision" : -1,
        "dateFrom" : "2018-12-01 12:00:00",
        "dateTo" : "2018-12-02 12:00:00"
    }
}

json_str = json.dumps(js_data)

r = requests.post(f"https://iiko.biz:9900/api/0/events/eventsMetadata?access_token={token}&request_timeout={requestTimeout}", json= json_str)
```